# Where is the "Reading List" stored on the local computer? Not Bookmarks, Reading List

Tags: google-chrome

I want to access the "Reading List" files stored on the local computer, is that possible?
I can't find it in chrome subfolder?

Answer (score 3):

#### I want to access the "Reading List" files stored on the local computer

It's not stored locally but you can download it:

> There is an option to download your Reading List. I've done so twice
> in the last week. Steps are as follows:
>
> - Click your picture at top right of page
> - Click "Manage Your Google Account" button
> - Click "Data & Privacy" tab on left side of page
> - Scroll down page to "Data from apps and services you use" section
> - Under header, on right, is option to "Download or delete your data"
> - Select "Download your data"
> - "Google Takeout" page will open
> - Go to "Create a new export"
> - Under "Select data to include," click "Deselect all"
> - Scroll to "Chrome"
> - Check box to right of "Chrome"
> - Click "All Chrome data included" button
> - Click "Deselect all"
> - Click "ReadingList," then OK
> - Scroll to bottom of page; click "Next step"
> - "Choose file type, frequency & destination" option will appear
> - Delivery method default should be "Send download link via email"
> - Frequency default should be "Download once"
> - Leave "File type & size" as is
> - Click "Create export"

Source: [Where is the "Reading List" stored on the local computer? Not Bookmarks, Reading List. - Google Chrome Community](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/133586125/where-is-the-reading-list-stored-on-the-local-computer-not-bookmarks-reading-list?hl=en)

Comment: Thank you so much :)